# How to split character in string in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, split

I'm currently trying to split character in my string but I get stuck when trying to put the expression.

the actual character that I have is like this

5546A68996

and I am expecting to split it in one character each box like

```
5
5
4
6 
A
6
8
9
9
6
```

Is it possible to split it in SSRS?

Really need some help.

Comment: Need a bit more info. 
Do you mean that you want each character in it's own textbox? Is the string always 10 characters long? If the answer to either of these questions is no, then please EDIT your question and provide a few examples, and show what the expected final output would look like in your report based on those examples.

Comment: Please share your research and attempt with us as per the question guide.